# Include full screen image in beamer with text on it

Tags: beamer

I would like to include a full screen image in beamer and write "Thank you" in the middle of the bottom right hand quarter of the image in large letters (preferably in a nice font). To that end I have

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame one}
\end{frame}   
{
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
    \includepdf{bp.pdf}
}  
\end{document}
```

How can I write the text onto the image?

Alternatively I also tried

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}   
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame one}
\end{frame} 
\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-\oddsidemargin-1in}{-\rightmargin}
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{bp.jpg}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

but I am still not sure how to write on the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to use [the LaTeX package texpos](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/textpos) for tasks like these. It works well for placing pictures into presentations as well.

For wilder fonts, I'd recommend using LuaTeX or XeTeX instead. With those you can use all the *.otf and *.ttf fonts available on your system. Alternatively, you could add the text to your picture using another program (Inkscape for instance) and include the lot together.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\paperheight}

\begin{document}   
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame one}
\end{frame} 
\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-\oddsidemargin-1in}{-\rightmargin}
  \textcolor{blue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \begin{textblock}{.5}[.5,.5](0.75,0.75)%
\begin{centering}
\scalebox{8}{\textcolor{red}{Text!}}
\end{centering}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

[image: large text in lower right corner]